# How to delete a child and get the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not so good with jQuery and I need your help. First, let me explain the situation. I have an HTML table like this :

```
<table id="table">
<tr><td><img class="image" />test</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><img class="image" />test</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

What I need to do is to get the full content of the table : $("#table").html() but without the img tags. (But I do not want to delete them in the original content, only in the "copied" content)

I tried something like that : 
`$('#table').clone().find('.image').remove().parent().parent().html()`

But it is undefined (I guess as the element is removed, I cannot access it and get the parent).
How would you do it ?

Thanks

EDIT: To try to explain it better, the result I would need is :

```
<table id="table">
<tr><td>test</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Only `$('#report').clone().find('.plusImage').remove()` is good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('#report').clone().find('.plusImage').remove().html()` will not return the table's content.

```
// First clone table and save it to a new variable
var clonedTable = $('#table').clone();

// remove all img tags
clonedTable.find('img').remove();

// test it
console.log(clonedTable.html());
```

You can also use a regular expression to remove it from the string without cloning DOM:

```
var contentWithoutImg = $('#table').html().replace(/<img[^>]+\>/ig, '');
console.log(contentWithoutImg);
```

Comment: why not (reliably) clone the DOM?

Answer (score 3):

You can't chain a method for your table to `remove()` because it returns the element that is removed. [Hast has posted the proper answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21735591/1612146), but if you think you'll need this more than just once and wanted to create your own method to remove children and return the container, you can use the following:

```
$.fn.removeDesc = function(sel){
    return this.each(function(){
       $(this).find(sel).remove(); 
    });
}
```

You could then use it like so:

```
var tableHTML = $('#report').clone().removeDesc('.plusImage').html();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fpkc/)

Comment: Well, actually the chain moves away from the #table on the find(). $('#table').remove() would do return the table..